# Is there a way to use subquery result as a pattern when running copy/merge from stage in Snowflake?

Tags: variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I need to filter by filename pattern based on filename which starts with a date to merge new data from S3 to Snowflake.

```
MERGE INTO tablename
USING
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM '@s3bucketname/'  
        (file_format  => PARQUET, pattern=>'.*20220127.*.parquet')  
)
    ...
;
```

This works fine but I need to update the date.
I can get the right pattern string using this subquery:

```
select concat('.*', regexp_replace(current_date(),'-',''), '.*.parquet' );
```

but since "Table function argument is required to be a constant", I need to have it as a separate variable. If I set it as a variable, it works but using CTE like:

```
MERGE INTO tablename
USING
( with filename_date as (select concat('.*', regexp_replace(current_date(),'-',''), '.*.parquet' ))
    SELECT *
        FROM '@s3bucketname/'  
        (file_format  => PARQUET, pattern=>filename_date )  
)
    ...
;
```

does not work.
Is there a way to set it within the merge and avoid making a separate session variable?

Comment: This one worked for me :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453827/dynamic-stage-path-in-snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set it within the merge and avoid making a separate
> session variable?

No there is no way to do it. As you mentioned the pattern argument expects you to provide a constant. Even if you enter filename_date, it accepts it as 'filename_date', not as a variable.

You may write a stored procedure to calculate the date and execute a dynamic SQL using this date as the pattern of the stage object.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there some kind of analyze tool which would show, how was the pattern argument interpreted?

Comment: No, there is not, but whatever you write as a pattern, you will see it will not fail. Actually, in your sample query, the filename_date is the name of the CTE. It's not possible to access the returning value like this, but your query does not fail with an invalid identifier.

Comment: This is disappointing.  I want to set and use variables from within a Snowflake CTE.  For date filtering.