# Dynamic stage path in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I  have a stage path as below

```
copy into table1 as (
select $1:InvestorID::varchar as Investor_ID from  @company_stage/pbook/2022-03-10/Invor/part-00000-33cbc68b-69c1-40c0-943c-f586dfab3f49-c000.snappy.parquet

)
```

This is my S3 location `company_stage/pbook/2022-03-10/Invor`,

I need to make this dynamic:

I) I need to change this "2022-03-10"  folder to current date

II)it must take all parquet files in the folder automatically, without me mentioning of filename. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach. Your stage shouldn't include the date as part of the stage name because if it did, you would need a new stage every day. Better to define the stage as `company_stage/pbook/`.

To make it dynamic, I suggest using the `pattern` option together with the COPY INTO command. You could create a variable with the regex pattern expression using current_date(), something like this:

```
set mypattern = '\.*'||to_char(current_date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'\.*';
```

Then use this variable in your COPY INTO command like this:

```
copy into table1 as (
select $1:InvestorID::varchar as Investor_ID from  @company_stage/pbook/ pattern = $mypattern
)
```

Of course you can adjust your pattern matching as you see fit.

Comment: How to permanently set variable , right now if I close this variable is gone